# Eagle has different shape for pads for through hole components why?

Tags: soldering, eaglecad, pad

While I understand that have 2 distinct shapes helps in determining which is pin 1, why does eagle have so many shapes: square, round, octagon, long, offset. Which is recommended under what circumstances?

Comment: This could easily turn into a generic question that's not specific to EAGLE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As well as being useful for marking particular pins, a square, octagonal or oblong pad has more copper area than a round hole of the same width. Through hole components such as connectors and large capacitors often have significant mechanical stress placed on them while the device is being operated or repaired. A larger copper area is better able to resist the track from being torn off the board, and the increased amount of solder on the larger pad also makes the joint stronger.

The pads on DIP ICs are often elongated to get maximum surface area while still allowing tracks to go between them. A multi-row pin header may use hexagonal or square pads instead, because there isn't enough room between the rows for elongated pads. Hexagonal pads provide a bit more room for routing tracks at 45° than square pads (effectively the same as a round pad but with added strength).

You don't *have* to use the pads that Eagle gives you. I am working on a PCB that is pretty tightly packed and I needed a bit more space, so I created modified DIP packages with smaller round pads. This gave me enough room to squeeze one more track in between the rows of a ROM chip (hope I never have to remove any of the ICs from this board once they are soldered in, because those smaller pads probably won't survive!).

Comment: Are you saying that the thin outline round pads were not sufficient for your use?

Comment: The standard DIP IC pad is elongated and has a length of ~0.1 inches. My pads are 0.05 inch round - same hole size and pad diameter, but saving 0.05 inches either side of the pin. That's another 0.1 inches of PCB space available!

Answer (score 1):

Because there are circumstances that you need to mark a pin in between of a series of pins. Each pin shape acts like a symbol. The pin shape recommendation depends on the allowed clearance between the pads (set by fabrication process), and your design. If it is High speed PCB then you have to account for signal interference, capacitance between pins, etc. But in general pin shapes are just used to mark the pins.

Comment: By the way, I found that there are various drill sizes which changes the size of the pad/pin. It is also possible to just enter a drill size using the keyboard. Is it true that the PCB manufacturer will only do certain sizes and I have to find out what they are and use them?

Comment: yes, you ask them to give you their specification on their available technologies. They will provide you all the details.

Comment: Low cost shops might require you to use a limited set of drill sizes. Full service shops will have a large selection available, and adjust up to the nearest size they have (within your allowed tolerances) if you use a size they don't have.